# How do I tell the version of Entity Framework I am using at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Is there a method or property on one of the EF classes to tell me? Must I write code to extract it out of the EF assembly?

Comment: which language? C# or vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `System.Reflection` to achieve this.

C#

```
var entityAssembly = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.Entity");
var assemblyVersion = entityAssembly != null ? entityAssembly.ImageRuntimeVersion : "";
```

VB.NET

```
Dim u As Assembly = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.Entity")
Dim assemblyVersion = IIf(entityAssembly Is Not Nothing, entityAssembly.ImageRuntimeVersion, "")
```

Disclaimer: Please note that [`Assembly.LoadWithPartialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368.aspx) is obslete from ASP.NET Framework 2.0